# How to Disable Long Press on all Images using Javascript on Mobile Browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile

Want to Disable Long press on all images in the webpage.
Could anyone recommend me a simple way to do it.Also I'm a newbie to Java Script.

I've tried "pointer-events:none" in CSS.But it disabled clicking too.
I've used the images as a Hyperlink so clicking can't be avoided.

Comment: Absolutely no idea what "disable long press" means

Comment: @Liam In Mobile Browser,we can long press on an image and there appears option for saving and sharing that image.So to disable that

Answer (score -1):

```js
function absorbEvent_(event) {
  var e = event || window.event;
  e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation && e.stopPropagation();
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  e.returnValue = false;
  return false;
}

function preventLongPressMenu(node) {
  node.ontouchstart = absorbEvent_;
  node.ontouchmove = absorbEvent_;
  node.ontouchend = absorbEvent_;
  node.ontouchcancel = absorbEvent_;
}

function init() {
  preventLongPressMenu(document.getElementById('theimage'));
}
```

Source: https://newbedev.com/disabling-the-context-menu-on-long-taps-on-android

Comment: This also disables short taps.